# VIN decoder api

Tags: api, vin

I know this is not a question to ask here, but we have googled for hours and cannot find what we need.
What we need is a company that has an API that we can use to find information about new vehicles.
We transport new vehicles (europe only) and I have written a recognition based on the VIN number, which works well, but only for 3 brands.
Now we will soon be working for other brands also, so I want to buy this information in stead of developing it ourself again.

What we need is an API where we can drop a VIN number, and it will return us

- the brand
- the model
- the dimensions  (height, length and width)
- the type of fuell

this is the minimal info than we need.
I need to use this API from a c# project.
The vehicles are for the European market, so sites that return American model names cannot be used here.  (nhtsa is not an option because of this)
It does not have to be free, we are willing to pay if not too expensive

Does anybody knows where I need to be for this ?

Comment: https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/ although that's US, it might be helpful.

Comment: @Duston Thank you for your effort, but I wrote in my question that this site cannot be used by me because it has only american models, no europian

Comment: @einSelbst No unfortunatly not, if you find something I would appreciate if you would share it